# How to connect to a CEFSharp application using selenium-webdriver in Node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, cefsharp

I have a CEFSharp application, which listens to port 8088 on launching. After the application is launched, I can see opened sites in `http://localhost:8088`. And I have chromedriver.exe in my system `PATH`.

Now I want to use selenium-webdriver in Node.js to connect to the CefSharp app through port 8088. But failed. My Node.js code looks like:

```
const {Builder, By, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
let o = new chrome.Options();

let driver = new Builder()
    .setChromeOptions(o)
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .usingServer('http://localhost:8088/')
    .build();

driver.findElement(By.id('q')).then((res) => {
    console.log('Resolve: ', res);
    driver.quit();
}).catch(error => {
    console.log('Reject: ', error);
});
```

It gives error:

```
Reject:
UnsupportedOperationError: newSession:
(node:20900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: UnsupportedOperationError: newSession: 
    at parseHttpResponse (c:\xxx\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:578:11)
    at Executor.execute (c:\xxx\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:489:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
(node:20900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20900) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Anybody know why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: Last I checked you couldn't connect to an already running browser with selenium. How does it behave if you try connecting to Chrome?

Comment: @amaitland If I change the browser to Chrome (not CEF), it will open a new Chrome window.

Comment: Search for selenium chrome driver connect to running instance or something similar. I don't believe you can. The general CEF instructions are https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver.md

Comment: Maybe puppeteer is an option for you,  it can connect to a running instance

Comment: @amaitland Finally I used Python driver instead. It has the API to accept a remote debugging port as parameter, which allows us to connect to a running instance.